Plot a chart on a dynamic common date row using VBA
i want to plot below data set.

since each date are different, i create a common all date row and trying to plot a multiple line chart with diffent date horizon on the same x-axis.
below is the code i am trying (not complete)
sub plot_chart()

    Range("2:2,3:3,5:5,8:8,11:11,14:14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineStacked).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "Sheet3!$2:$2,Sheet3!$3:$3,Sheet3!$5:$5,Sheet3!$8:$8,Sheet3!$11:$11,Sheet3!$14:$14" _
        )
    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 230
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollectioin(1).ApplyDataLables

End sub

The above code works without any error, but that chart is not what i wanted.

I want each line shows from corresponding date(date1, date2,,,) starting point to ending point and for the missing values part, just simply ignore it.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator. Please share what's your expected output.


Change the layout of tables before creating a chart

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iCol As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Dim arrData, arrData2, rngData As Range, allDateRng As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, oSht As Worksheet, xRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, aRow, iMin As Long, iMax As Long
    aRow = Array(2, 5, 8, 11) ' row# of table blocks
    ' create a copy
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet
    ' load all data into an array
    Set allDateRng = oSht.Range("A" & aRow(0)).CurrentRegion
    arrData = allDateRng.Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    Set xRng = allDateRng.Resize(1, ColCnt - 1).Offset(, 1)
    ' get the min date
    iMin = Application.Min(oSht.Rows(aRow(0)))
    ' loop through data blocks, transform table
    For i = 1 To UBound(aRow)
        Set rngData = oSht.Range("A" & aRow(i)).CurrentRegion
        arrData2 = rngData.Value
        ReDim arrRes(1, 1 To ColCnt)
        arrRes(0, 1) = arrData2(1, 1)
        arrRes(1, 1) = arrData2(2, 1)
        For j = 2 To UBound(arrData2, 2)
            iCol = CLng(arrData2(1, j)) - iMin + 2
            arrRes(0, iCol) = arrData2(1, j)
            arrRes(1, iCol) = arrData2(2, j)
        Next
        rngData.Resize(, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
    Next
    
    Dim oShp As Shape, oCht As Chart, oSer As Series, serRng As Range
    ' collect source data range of chart
    For i = 1 To UBound(aRow)
        Set serRng = allDateRng.Rows(1).Offset(aRow(i) - aRow(0) + 1)
        Set allDateRng = Application.Union(allDateRng, serRng)
    Next
    ' add a chart
    Set oShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers)
    ' relocate chart , modify as needed
    oShp.Top = oSht.Range("A15").Top: oShp.Left = 0
    Set oCht = oShp.Chart
    ' add the first series (All Data)
    oCht.SetSourceData allDateRng
End Sub




just a quick questions, if the date format is "YYYY QQ" rather than "YYYY/MM/DD", will it affect the code? i tried it and it is giving me some errors. I have hard time to understand the "iCol = CLng(arrData2(1, j)) - iMin + 2" line of code, could you pleases elaborate? i know iMin is a date, however, i beleive "arrData2(1, j)" is a value. why do we subtract the 2?.
